# MS Power Query - eliminating duplicates in a set of delimited values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, grouping, powerquery

I have a excel file with data something like below:

[image]

A1 | 13,15,14,16,17

A2 | 13,16

I want the data to look like

A3 | 13, 15, 16, 17

Merge the selected cells data into single cell, avoid duplicate values.

Also, while doing this compare the values to other cells and then exclude those cells.

Say, B1 | 13,14

Then Final Output should not include values from B1

A3 | 15, 16, 17

I tried using Text Join, Unique functions but none of them are working. I found out about XMLconvert function but that is also not supporting excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since OP has tagged **`Excel Formula`** then one could try the following :

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A3</kbd>

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,UNIQUE(TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(","&A1:A2,",",SEQUENCE(,MAX(LEN(A1:A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A2,",",))+1))),","),3)))
```

---

Or,

```
=ARRAYTOTEXT(DROP(UNIQUE(REDUCE("",A1:A2,LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,TEXTSPLIT(y,,","))))),1))
```

---

With Power Query, you can try using the following `M` Code:

[image]

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="DelimitedTab"]}[Content],
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Column1"),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Split Column by Delimiter"),
    Column1 = Text.Combine(#"Removed Duplicates"[Column1],",")
in
    Column1
```

---

Or,  if the data is limited then one could use the following as well:

[image]

---

```
=ARRAYTOTEXT(UNIQUE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",,A1:A2),,",")))
```

---

Edit:

As per OP's comment:

> *Also, while doing this compare the values to other cells and then*
> *exclude those cells. Say, B1 | 13,14 Then Final Output should not*
> *include values from B1 A3 | 15, 16, 17*

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A4</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, SORT(UNIQUE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",,A1:A2),,","))), 
     TEXTJOIN(",",1,IF(ISERROR(XMATCH(α, TEXTSPLIT(B1,","))),α,"")))
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A5</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, SORT(UNIQUE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",,A1:A2),,","))), 
     ARRAYTOTEXT(FILTER(α, ISNA(XMATCH(α,TEXTSPLIT(B1,","))))))
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A6</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α,SORT(UNIQUE(--TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",,A1:A2),,","))),
     TEXTJOIN(",",,REPT(α,ISERR(SEARCH(α,B1)))))
```

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A7</kbd>

```
=LET(α,UNIQUE(SORT(--TEXTSPLIT(A1&","&A2,,","))),ARRAYTOTEXT(TOCOL(α/ISERR(SEARCH(α,B1)),3)))
```

---

Test cases:

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Comment: Also, while doing this compare the values to other cells and then exclude those cells. Say, B1 | 13,14

Then Final Output should not include values from B1

A3 | 15, 16, 17

Comment: That is a different question ! How do you want using `Excel Formula` or `Power Query`?

Comment: I will prefer Excel Formula if possible.

Comment: @SiddheshGhirnikar updated formula:

Comment: No, earlier operation was correct. I just need additional action to be done.

A1 | 13,15,14,16,17
A2 | 13,16
B1 | 13, 14

I want the data to look like. Combine A1 & A2 and exclude B1.

A3 | 15, 16, 17

Comment: I have added all alternatives you can use as per suit

Comment: Can you please look at my question one more time?

Comment: @SiddheshGhirnikar have seen the updated formula yet?

Comment: Value Not Available Error
A value is not available to the formula or function.

Comment: Are you using `MS365`? Then then formula should be working on your end

Comment: Dont mind but your initial question was different, now when you have changed it becomes completely different so those who have invested time, they have to again rework on it, it will be helpful if you post new question as a new post.

Comment: Now, it is not throwing any error but not working as expected after doing some testing on it. for eg. if the there is only 1 value in B1 and that value is in the middle in either A1 or A2 then result is including it.

Comment: @SiddheshGhirnikar I am saying again, your initial question was completely different, you need to post a new question, the forum don't run as you are expecting! As well as you can see my updates where it is working

Answer (score 1):

My 2-cents:

[image]

Formula in `A3`:

```
=LET(x,SORT(UNIQUE(--TEXTSPLIT(A1&","&A2,,","))),TEXTJOIN(", ",,IFNA(IF(XMATCH(x,--TEXTSPLIT(B1,,",")),""),x)))
```

Comment: Everything is perfect now; except I need the A1:A2 to be a range rather than specific cells. :)

Comment: @SiddheshGhirnikar also if this one is working why are you again asking for a change. Cant you make the necessary changes.

Answer (score 0):

Powerquery to return unique items from range **Table1** would be

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content]
in Text.Combine(List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(Source[Column1], each Text.Split(_,", ")))),", ")
```

then file close and load back to excel